# on Nivo 1: How can I move the bars up to start where my minValue is set? 2: How can I make the y value to show on top of the bar within a circle?

Tags: reactjs, nivo-react

I need help with two things!

1. My graph has different minValues. Some of them start at like 30 (as shown in the pic)
   But when the min value is above 0. The bars tend to overflow and it covers up the bottom of the graph and the ticks.
   How can I make the graph start at my minValue?
2. I want to make the y value show on top of the bar inside a circle. (like the annotations for design purposes) Any idea how I could do that?

Here's my code.

```
enter code       <ResponsiveBar
    margin={{
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 80
    }}
    data={data}
    maxValue={range.max}
    minValue={range.min}
    keys={["y"]}
    indexBy="x"
    colorBy="indexValue"
    padding={0.6}
    axisBottom={{
      tickSize: 0
    }}
    colors={["#00E7CB", "#929292"]}
    layers={[
      "grid",
      refsLayer,
      "markers",
      "axes",
      "areas",
      "bars",
      "slices",
      "dots",
      "legends"
    ]}
  />
```

[Here's the picture of the code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmt5R.png)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486807/5711949