# Nivo responsive bar chart x-axis overflow with minValue and maxValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bar-chart, nivo-slider

I am having an issue with the Nivo responsive bar chart. I have set the "minValue" and the "maxValue" in my chart props per the [documentation](https://nivo.rocks/bar/). The data passed to the chart contains valid in range values of the "minValue" and "maxValue."

When manually specifying "minValue" and "maxValue" the bars overflow on the x-axis and do not display properly.

A little context... I don't want to set the "minValue" and "maxValue" as "auto" because I need to show the floor and ceiling of the possible numbers. Setting it "auto" will cause the chart to automatically calculate the min and the max values based on the lowest and highest number in the dataset. The bars display correctly on the x-axis and don't overflow when using the "auto" setting.

Does anyone know why the bars don't display properly when specifying custom "minValue" and "maxValue"? Any ideas on what might be wrong?

[Demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-https-v20ezo?file=/src/App.js:0-2087)

[image: Screenshot of overflow issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `clamp` value to `true` in your `valueScale` property, ie:

```
<ResponsiveBar
  ...
  valueScale={{ 
    type: 'linear',
    min: minVal * 0.8,
    max: maxVal * 1.2,
    clamp: true
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't see that clamp property anywhere in the docs. That worked and is just what I needed to get the bar chart to work properly.

Comment: I was having trouble finding it too, so I started cmd clicking on component props and reading type definitions